# Vuetify + Vee-Validate - Multi-Step Form - avoid validate on mount

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I have a multi-step form built with Vuetify and Vee-Validate (Zod rules).

When a field is created dynamically, whether by a repeater or by mounting the next step, the validation is applied automatically, causing error messages, although the user has yet to have the chance to do something.

This can be reproduced in the following playground:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-s7qa75?file=src%2FApp.vue